# Keep HTTP or HTTPS on .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/profile/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://whatsee-profile.s3.amazonaws.com/$1 [R,L]
```

It [redirects my fake links](http://whatsee.plugapps.net/api/profile/4ed50303c5f02a7c46aaff865e570913.png) to the real ones and works great! But I need to keep the original **HTTP** or **HTTPS** protocol before the url. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/profile/
RewriteRule (http|https):\/\/whatsee.plugapps.net\/api\/profile\/(.*) $1://whatsee-profile.s3.amazonaws.com/$2 [R,L]
```

Any idea what is wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It exists several ways of doing it.
Here is one working solution

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ - [env=protoc:https]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ - [env=protoc:http]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/profile/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:protoc}://whatsee-profile.s3.amazonaws.com/$1 [R,L]
```