# How to redirect selected pages from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I would like to redirect some of my pages on my site from `http` to `https`.
Those selected pages all contain a keyword, for example "`purchase`"

```
http://domain.com/producta-purchase >https...

http://domain.com/productb-purchase >https...
```

How can I do it in `.htaccess`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep HTTP or HTTPS on .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222238/keep-http-or-https-on-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

You can use that in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} purchase [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```